# WPF unexpected ICollectionView behavior

Tags: c#, wpf, icollectionview

I'm new to WPF, and just learning how things work.  My endgoal is to have a datagrid for each heading which displays totals from a collection of items associated with each category.

But I'm seeing some unexpected behavior.  I expect to see this output:

Heading1
Category1
Category2

Heading2
Category3

What I actually see is this:

Heading1
Category3

Heading2
Category3

I'm stumped as to why.  Hoping somebody could shed a little light.  Thanks for any help!

Here's my code:

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="TestApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestApp"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <StackPanel>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Headings}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" />
                        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                            <DataGrid.Columns>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="" Binding="{Binding Description}" Width="*" />
                            </DataGrid.Columns>
                        </DataGrid>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public ObservableCollection<HeadingViewModel> Headings { get; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;

            var category1 = new CategoryViewModel()
            {
                Id = 1,
                Description = "Category 1",
                HeadingId = 1,
            };

            var category2 = new CategoryViewModel()
            {
                Id = 2,
                Description = "Category 2",
                HeadingId = 1,
            };

            var category3 = new CategoryViewModel()
            {
                Id = 3,
                Description = "Category 3",
                HeadingId = 2,
            };

            var categories = new ObservableCollection<CategoryViewModel>();
            categories.Add(category1);
            categories.Add(category2);
            categories.Add(category3);

            var heading1 = new HeadingViewModel(categories)
            {
                Id = 1,
                Description = "Heading 1",
            };

            var heading2 = new HeadingViewModel(categories)
            {
                Id = 2,
                Description = "Heading 2",
            };

            this.Headings = new ObservableCollection<HeadingViewModel>();
            this.Headings.Add(heading1);
            this.Headings.Add(heading2);
        }
```

HeadingViewModel.cs

```
public class HeadingViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ICollectionView Categories { get; }

        public HeadingViewModel(ObservableCollection<CategoryViewModel> categories)
        {
            this.Categories = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(categories);
            this.Categories.Filter = CategoriesFilter;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private bool CategoriesFilter(object item)
        {
            var category = item as CategoryViewModel;
            return category.HeadingId == this.Id;
        }

        private int id;
        public int Id
        {
            get
            {
                return id;
            }
            set
            {
                this.id = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
                Categories.Refresh();
            }
        }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
```

CategoryViewModel.cs

```
public class CategoryViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public CategoryViewModel() {}

        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        private int? headingId;
        public int? HeadingId
        {
            get
            {
                return headingId;
            }
            set
            {
                this.headingId = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, `CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(categories)` will return the same `ICollectionView` instance for the same input, no matter how often you call it.

Since you pass the same `categories` to both `HeadingViewModel` constructors, the second constructor `this.Categories.Filter = CategoriesFilter` will override the filter for both headings.

Answer (score 1):

grek40 gets the gold star for telling me what the problem was - but here's the solution for anyone else that stumbles across this:

In HeadingViewModel.cs change this line:

```
this.Categories = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(categories);
```

to this:

```
this.Categories = new CollectionViewSource { Source = categories }.View;
```

That returns a new instance of the viewsource for each instance of Heading which solves the issue.